# react native firebase sign out method deletes my email and password data when trying to sign in

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have a signout method in my react native app that each time i sign out and try to sign back in my email and password is not remembered in firebase. The database shows the email and password but for some reason when i enter my email and password it doesn't log in. I can't find what i'm doing wrong.

here is my sign in screen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';


export default function LoginScreen({navigation}) {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')


    const onFooterLinkPress1 = () => {
        navigation.navigate("Registration")
    }

    const onFooterLinkPress2 = () => {
        navigation.navigate("ResetPassword")
    }

    const onLoginPress = () => {
        firebase
            .auth()
            .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((response) => {
                const uid = response.user.uid
                const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
                usersRef
                    .doc(uid)
                    .get()
                    .then(firestoreDocument => {
                        if (!firestoreDocument.exists) {
                            alert("User does not exist anymore.")
                            return;
                        }
                        const user = firestoreDocument.data()
                        
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        alert(error)
                    });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error)
            })
        }

    return (
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/backgroundCopySilk.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../../assets/logoCopy.png')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='E-mail'
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                    value={email}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                    value={password}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => onLoginPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Log in</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.footerView}>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Don't have an account? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress1} style={styles.footerLink}>Sign up</Text></Text>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.footerView}>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Forgot Password? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress2} style={styles.footerLink}>Reset Here</Text></Text>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}
```

Here is my sign out screen

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, Text, Linking, TouchableOpacity, View,ImageBackground, Alert } from 'react-native'
import styles from './styles';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config';
import { auth } from 'firebase';
import {Spacer} from '../spacer';



export default function ProductScreen({navigation}){

    const logOutPress = () => {
        try {
        auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => { navigation.navigate("Login"),
        alert('You have signed out')})
    } catch(error){
    console.log('Unable to logout')}
    }

   const yalaPress = () =>  Alert.alert( "You're about to leave the app",[
    { text: "Cancel",
        onPress: ()=> console.log('Cancel Pressed')},
    {text: "Ok", 
        onPress: () => Linking.openURL('https://yalajets.com/')
    }],{ cancelable: false }  );


    return(
<ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/backgroundCopySilk.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
<View style={styles.container}>

<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={()=> navigation.navigate('LawnCare')}
style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Commercial Lawn Care</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Vehicle Car Detail</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Pharmaceuticals</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Personal Fitness</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Massage with Catch These Hands</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<TouchableOpacity 
onPress={yalaPress}
style={styles.button}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Luxury Private Flights with Yala Jets</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>

<Spacer/>
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={()=> logOutPress()}>
<Text style={styles.buttonText}>Log Out</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
</ImageBackground>
    )
};
```

also here is my sign up screen

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Image, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View,ImageBackground } from 'react-native'
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view';
import styles from './styles';
import { firebase } from '../../firebase/config'


export default function RegistrationScreen({navigation}) {
    const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('')
    const [lastName, setLastName] = useState('')
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const [confirmPassword, setConfirmPassword] = useState('')
    const onFooterLinkPress = () => {
        navigation.navigate('Login')
    }

   
    const onRegisterPress = () => {
        if (password !== confirmPassword) {
            alert("Passwords don't match.")
            return
        }
        firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((response) => {
                const uid = response.user.uid
                const data = {
                    id: uid,
                    email,
                    firstName,
                    lastName
                };
                const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
                usersRef
                    .doc(uid)
                    .set(data)
                    .then(() => {
                        navigation.navigate("Products", {user: data})
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        alert(error)
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error)
        });
    }

    return (
        <ImageBackground source={require('../../../assets/backgroundCopySilk.jpg')} style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <KeyboardAwareScrollView
                style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}
                keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always">
                <Image
                    style={styles.logo}
                    source={require('../../../assets/logoCopy.png')}
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='First Name'
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    onChangeText={(text) => setFirstName(text)}
                    value={firstName}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='Last Name'
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    onChangeText={(text) => setLastName(text)}
                    value={lastName}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholder='E-mail'
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
                    value={email}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Password'
                    onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
                    value={password}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TextInput
                    style={styles.input}
                    placeholderTextColor="#aaaaaa"
                    secureTextEntry
                    placeholder='Confirm Password'
                    onChangeText={(text) => setConfirmPassword(text)}
                    value={confirmPassword}
                    underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                    autoCapitalize="none"
                />
                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.button}
                    onPress={() => onRegisterPress()}>
                    <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>Create account</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <View style={styles.footerView}>
                    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Already got an account? <Text onPress={onFooterLinkPress} style={styles.footerLink}>Log in</Text></Text>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For create user You need add some Data in the method:

```
firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .then((response) => {
                const uid = response.user.uid
                const data = {
                    id: uid,
                    email: useremail,
                    firstName: firstname,
                    lastName: lastname
                };
                const usersRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users')
                usersRef
                    .doc(uid)
                    .set(data, {merge: true})
                    .then(() => {
                        navigation.navigate("Products", {user: data})
                    })
                    .catch((error) => {
                        alert(error)
                    });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                alert(error)
        });
```

You make create login method  where You chceck is a new user for example like this.

```
emailPassRegister(mail, password) {
    this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(mail, pasword).then(ref => {
      if (ref.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
        // method for new user
        this.addNewUser(ref.user);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      } else {
        // method for reapeater user
        this.updataUser(ref.user);
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });
  }
```

but every time if You set new data You need use {merge: true}, because if document or filed does not exist is created if exist is updated.
I hope that help You in You problem.

method to register user:

```
RegisterUser() {
  emailPassRegister(**username from input**, **password from input**);
}
```

Comment: are you saying to replace my onLoginPress method with this new method above?

Comment: This is suggestion, but if work for You, the same way, why not

Comment: i added data into the email but i had to change email: useremail to email:email as useremail was not a recognized variable

Comment: Hi C.Evulukwu Anaba i update my answer for another method , i forgote about this, sorry. I hope that help in You problem